# Asbestos in the walls

Tags: drill

We had some worker to instal a fitted wardrobe into our kids room. Our house was completed 2005 so perhaps started to build 2003. I know asbestos was banned in 1999 so I believe there is no chance that our walls will have asbestos right? The worker did only a bit of drilling and had a special hoover which pretty much took all the dust away. Afterwords when he left I did some good cleaning myself just because my son is allergic to dust.
Am I being a bit overthinking that there could be asbestos in the walls? Thanks

Comment: Based on dates, there should not be any asbestos in the walls. But even if there is, reasonable precautions (which were done here) is all you need. The problem with asbestos is if you work with it day after day, year after year. Not a one-off like this. DON'T WORRY.

Comment: No chance of asbestos on a 2003 build. At that time, "mesothelioma" was the most expensive keyword in paid web search, so everyone knew about it.  It was functionally banned a lot earlier than 1999.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the dates involved there's no reasonable chance of there being asbestos in your walls.

Even if there was, drilling a few holes and subsequently vacuuming up the dust makes it impossible for there to be any significant health risks. That would  simply not be enough asbestos to be concerned about.

Answer (score -1):

The only guarantee is to bring some dust to a testing place.

Based on your dates there should be none, but who knows.

There are unconfirmed stories on Internet, that some of China-made drywall still has asbestos in it.

To be 100% sure and to protect your child, have it tested.